# How to unzip on Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, unzip, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I have a file names awscliv2.zip and I'm trying to unzip it.

So first I tried:

```
unzip awscliv2.zip
```

But got:

> -bash: unzip: command not found

And then I tried:

```
tar xvf awscliv2.zip
```

But got:

> tar: This does not look like a tar archive
>
> tar: Skipping to next header
>
> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: Consider using Python's `zipfile` module. That said, Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing code_; a question about available tools on a specific Linux distro is a better fit for [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install `unzip` using:

```
sudo yum install unzip
```

Comment: If you are using Amazon-Linux 2 then unzip package is already install. you can fire the command like this ``` unzip your-file.zip```.